# Appending to next row the product of two columns previous row

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 100, 1.1], 
                   [2, float('NaN'), 0.97],
                   [3, float('NaN'), 1.1], 
                   [4, float('NaN'), 1.2], 
                   [5, float('NaN'), 1]], columns=['day', 'Amount', 'Rate'])

df

╔═════╦═════════╦══════╗
║ day ║ Amount  ║ Rate ║
╠═════╬═════════╬══════╣
║   1 ║ 100     ║ 1.1  ║
║   2 ║ NaN     ║ 0.97 ║
║   3 ║ NaN     ║ 1.1  ║
║   4 ║ NaN     ║ 1.2  ║
║   5 ║ NaN     ║ 1.0  ║
╚═════╩═════════╩══════╝
```

I need that the day+1 Amount = day-1 Amount * day-1 Rate. So the output should be:

```
╔═════╦═════════╦══════╗
║ day ║ Amount  ║ Rate ║
╠═════╬═════════╬══════╣
║   1 ║ 100     ║ 1.1  ║
║   2 ║ 110     ║ 0.97 ║
║   3 ║ 106.7   ║ 1.1  ║
║   4 ║ 117.37  ║ 1.2  ║
║   5 ║ 140.844 ║ 1.0  ║
╚═════╩═════════╩══════╝
```

Is there any pandas method to acchieve this? Because I'm doing it with loops and I feel that it is not efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with [`Series.cumprod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html) and multiple by `100`, last replace missing values in `Amount` column:

```
df['Amount'] = df['Amount'].fillna(df['Rate'].shift().cumprod().mul(100))
print (df)
   day   Amount  Rate
0    1  100.000  1.10
1    2  110.000  0.97
2    3  106.700  1.10
3    4  117.370  1.20
4    5  140.844  1.00
```

If want use first value of `Amount` column:

```
first = df.loc[0, 'Amount']
df['Amount'] = df['Rate'].shift().cumprod().mul(first).fillna(first)
print (df)
   day   Amount  Rate
0    1  100.000  1.10
1    2  110.000  0.97
2    3  106.700  1.10
3    4  117.370  1.20
4    5  140.844  1.00
```